# Hibernate kills session but connection stays open

Tags: hibernate

I make a software with Hibernate + JSF. But realized when I make a session with Hibernate, even though I close a session `(session.close())`, the connection is still open in MySQL.

```
show FULL PROCESSLIST

2   root    localhost:55850 repositorionew  Query   0       
5   root    localhost:55884 repositorionew  Sleep   110     
6   root    localhost:55885 repositorionew  Sleep   110     
7   root    localhost:55886 repositorionew  Sleep   110     
8   root    localhost:55906 repositorionew  Sleep   108     
9   root    localhost:55907 repositorionew  Sleep   108
```

Each session opens, one connect is created but not closed even when I use close.

Someone edited my post. The main problem is that when the time ends of the connection, it does not close but restarts.

Comment: Are you using spring? or Do you have any sort of transaction manager? Also, are you using connection pooling?

Comment: this is precisely the problem. C3p0 I use to manage connections. but when I edit the timeout, it does not close the connection, only restarts.
When the timeout reaches the number you want, it creates a new connection. and is generating new connections when it reaches the timeout. not use Spring.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you have one of these two issues:

[How can I prevent Hibernate + c3p0 + MySql creating large numbers of sleeping connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768263/how-can-i-prevent-hibernate-c3p0-mysql-creating-large-numbers-of-sleeping-co)

or

[Hibernate : closing the session factory does not close the c3p0 connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298437/hibernate-closing-the-session-factory-does-not-close-the-c3p0-connection-pool)

I hope that it helps.

Cheers

Comment: Someone edited my post. The main problem is that when the time ends of the connection, it does not close but restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Is not this default behavior of connection pooling? I don't think that closed session means closed connection. Not in the case of connection pooling at all.

What happen when you close correctly you app?

Comment: Someone edited my post. The main problem is that when the time ends of the connection, it does not close but restarts.

Comment: It would correspond to pool as the pool just stores count of active connections equals to some defined number - in configuration.