# Which parameter in the Hibernate Configuration file determines the Query/Sleep time in MySql?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have an application designed in Hibernate, its Sleep time gets resets after it reaches 600 in MySql Administrator. Which parameter determines the time for sleep in the MySQL? I have attached a screenshot here. 
[image]

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25461 check this

Comment: @ Shoaib Chikate Thank you for your answer. Could it be possible to control by using hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: Are you getting connection closed after some period of time??

Comment: yes that sleep connection gets closed after 600 seconds

Comment: Dont forget to accept answer if you find it appropriate....Thanks :)

Comment: sure Shoaib Chikate.Thanks :)

Comment: hi  Shoaib Chikate i am getting the following error : Unknown database 'Test;autoReconnect=true'

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
 <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0/yourDBName;autoReconnect-true</property>
```

Link for above answer is [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=930285)

Or [follow this link for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768263/how-can-i-prevent-hibernate-c3p0-mysql-creating-large-numbers-of-sleeping-co)